# How to place small image before url in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, favicon

How can I place my icon before URL?

Comment: Very nice for you. Now, what is your question? What is the problem you are having with the `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Oded - good luck...  have you looked at his question history?  Out of his 48 questions, there are maybe 5 that actually provide any more detail than the title.  @Fraz - Portions of http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html may be helpful if you find your questions aren't getting satisfactory answers.  Particularly http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - which is exactly why one needs to keep trying to educate such a user.

Comment: If some one have any problem thats why he is posting a question on a forum like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a favicon, here is a wonderful link about how to create one.

[CSharpCorner Favicon Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/afenster/291/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This icon is called Favicon you can get more help on this at following location.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/favicon.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display an icon before/after all links (not a favicon as others have assumed (fair assumtion however) ) then do it in CSS.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Attach_icons_to_anything_with_CSS

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updated due to first comment that this is not an answer.

Your question is rather unclear, but I presume you mean you want your website to display a picture in a browser just before the actual url text. This is called a favicon.

[Wikipedia explains it well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Comment: This is not an answer and should have been posted as a comment to the question.

Comment: One might equally say that this wasn't a question either, and that I at least tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

use code below to put image.png before the url

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image.png" />
```